# Is there a value for $a$ other than a factor or a multiple of $c$ in $\frac{a}{b}=\frac{c}{d}$

Tags: fractions

Suppose $a,b,c,d$ to be whatever quantities whatsoever that satisfy the proportion $\frac{a}{b}=\frac{c}{d}$. Is there a value for $a$ other than a factor or a multiple of $c$. Or, is there a value for $b$ other than a factor or a multiple of $d$.

I am sure there cannot be such a value but at the same time there is no way for me to prove it.

Comment: Take for example $a=b=35,c=d=66$

Comment: @kingW3 That's true but that's a very special case where the 2 fractions aren't really two fractions but simply 2 real numbers.

Comment: 4/6 = 6/9     4 is not a factor or multiple of 6. 6 is not a factor or multiple of 9. Instead of "factor or multiple", do you  mean "relatively prime"?

Comment: @PeterWebb But those two fractions can be simplified down to $2/3$. Yes, what I mean is what about relatively prime fractions ? Where the numerator and the denominator have no factors other than 1 ?

Answer (score 0):

The given expression is ad=bc if a and b are two different numbers such that their greatest common factor is 1

Case-1:
If Z is least common multiple of a and c, b=z/c and d=z/a clearly satisfies the equation. ( you may change the variables)

Case-2:
If cd=ad=0 then c may or may not be equal to a

Case-3:
if above are not the cases then they has to be surely equal.